# What is the auth method of google app?

Tags: android, ios, google-signin

For example, iOS/Android gmail/youtube/google map, when I click `signin`, it seems using web to let me login? What is the technique?

Answer (score 0):

Google Sign-In uses [OAuth 2.0](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect).

The process is:

1. Create an anti-forgery state token
2. Send an authentication request to Google
3. Confirm the anti-forgery state token
4. Exchange code for access token and ID token
5. Obtain user information from the ID token
6. Authenticate the user

Comment: The page that I input username/password, is it a webview or browser?